# Увеличение табличного пространства субд oracle

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Здравствуйте, есть 2 базы в оракле 11g, `data1` и `data2`. И в той и в этой базе есть табличное пространство `USERS`. На `data1` закончилось это табличное пространство и с 32 гигабайт надо увеличить до 130 гигабайт. Через `sql plus` перепробовал всякие разные команды

```
alter tablespace users add datafile 'с:/oracle/opdata/data1/users02.dbf' size 10000M ..
```

Создаётся, но не цепляется почему-то. Хотя всё успешно добавлено.

И такие команды

```
alter database datafile '...' resize <размер>
```

(Ругается на темпари что-то)

Или подскажите, что-нибудь графическое для работы с oracle.

Comment: (ругается на темпари что то) -- это конечно многое объясняет.

Comment: я точно не помню) сейчас дома, вроде так называется эта таблица)) TEMPORARY. Сегодня первый раз администрировал оракл)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize здесь не поможет, 32Гб - максимальный размер датафайла.
Давайте пробовать, добавим небольшой расширяемый датафайл:

```
alter tablespace "USERS" add datafile 'с:/oracle/opdata/data1/users02.dbf' size 10M reuse autoextend on next 10M maxsize unlimited;
```

Естественно, запускаем из-под администратора базы данных.
Далее, проверяем новый файл запросом:

```
select tablespace_name "Tablespace"
     , file_name "Filename"
     , bytes / 1024 / 1024 "Size MB"
     , maxbytes / 1024 / 1024 "Maximum Size MB"
     , autoextensible "Autoextensible"
  from
       sys.dba_data_files
 where 
       instr (lower (tablespace_name) ,lower ('USERS')) > 0
```

order by 1, 2;